# What is __ERC20Permit_init?

Tags: erc-20, tokens

I came across `__ERC20Permit_init` while reviewing some code. What purpose of this? I googled and found it out in the `Initializable.sol` of Oppenzeppelin's contract. But example codes in contract were used in different contracts. The code I reviewed was used in one contract. Is there any difference?

[Code snippet of the project]

```js
contract LPToken is ILPTokenInit, ILiquidStakingManagerChildContract, Initializable, ERC20PermitUpgradeable {
    //...
    constructor() initializer {}

    function init(
            address _deployer,
            address _transferHookProcessor,
            string calldata _tokenSymbol,
            string calldata _tokenName
         ) external override initializer {
            deployer = _deployer;
            transferHookProcessor = ITransferHookProcessor(_transferHookProcessor);
            __ERC20_init(_tokenName, _tokenSymbol);
            __ERC20Permit_init(_tokenName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't think there is a difference. `__ERC20Permit_init` initializes the {EIP712} domain separator using the `name` parameter, and setting `version` to "1". A domain separator helps to prevent a signature meant for one dApp from working in another.

- The `name` is the name of the dApp or protocol name.
- The current `version` is the version what the EIP712 standard calls a “signing domain”. This can be the version number of your dApp or platform. It prevents signatures from one dApp version from working with those of others.

See:

https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts-upgradeable/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/draft-ERC20PermitUpgradeable.sol

https://medium.com/metamask/eip712-is-coming-what-to-expect-and-how-to-use-it-bb92fd1a7a26

Answer (score 0):

I found this in the ERC20Permit.sol file under /contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Permit.sol

```
* @dev Implementation of the ERC20 Permit extension allowing approvals to be made via signatures, as defined in
 * https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2612[EIP-2612].
 *
 * Adds the {permit} method, which can be used to change an account's ERC20 allowance (see {IERC20-allowance}) by
 * presenting a message signed by the account. By not relying on `{IERC20-approve}`, the token holder account doesn't
 * need to send a transaction, and thus is not required to hold Ether at all.
```

so it looks like enables an allowance function on the ERC20 contract that you can change by signing a message instead of sending a transaction.